# How to change 'db_datareader' permission to 'public' for a login in azure sql server?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I created a new login and a new user in Azure SQL server database. 
What I want to do is providing a read only permission to this role for a single table in the database.
While doing this I ran the below script:

**EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'new_user'
GO**

But with this permission the new user can view all the tables in the database.
So I tried running the below script with 'public' role.

**EXEC sp_addrolemember N'public', N'new_user'
GO**

But its giving me this error:
"Membership of the public role cannot be changed."

How to provide only a single table read permission to the new user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the following statement on master database to create your new user login (mydb_user)

```
CREATE LOGIN mydb_user 
WITH PASSWORD = 'p@ssw0rd'
GO
```

Run below statements on the user database

```
CREATE USER mydb_user  FROM LOGIN mydb_user ;
GO
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.Events TO mydb_user;
```

I tested this on my side. It should work on your side.

Comment: It works! Thanks. Just a little correction. I think the last statement should be "GRANT SELECT ON dbo.Events TO mydb_user ".

Comment: Thank you I edited the answer for the benefit of future users looking for the same answer. Have a great day!